# EF4.1 How to I implement a CascadeDelete where two tables share records in one table?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I'm using EF4.1 Code First.  I have two classes which both have a one-to-one relationship with  a contact class.  When I remove a record in either of the two classes I want the associated entry in the contact class removed also.

ex:

```
public class User
{
   public virtual int ID { get; set; }
   ...
   public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
}

public class Admin
{
   public virtual int ID { get; set; }
   ...
   public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
   public virtual int ID { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

I tried various things with annotations and fluent API but could not yet manage to get a cascade delete working.  What is the correct way to implement this in EF 4.1 Code First?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work if you want to delete Users and Admins if a Contact is deleted:

```
public class User
{ 
   public int ID { get; set; }


   public int ContactId { get; set; }
   public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
}

public class Contact 
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public virtual List<User> Users {get; set;}

   public Contact()
   {
        Users = new List<User>();
   }
}
```

**While I believe you want to do the opposite, which means you need to make the Contact is the dependent entity**

```
public class User
{ 
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public bool IsAdmin {get; set;}
   public virtual List<Contact> {get; set;}

   public Contact()
   {
        Users = new List<User>();
   }
}

public class Contact 
{
   public int ID { get; set; }

   [ForiegnKey("Owner")]
   public int UserId {get; set;}
   public virtual User Owner {get; set;}
}
```

you can use other types of Inheritance other than TPC I'm using here, because DBMS doesn't support two mutually exclusive Foreign Keys

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work, because the AdminUser is part of the AdminGroup which is part of the User also, meaning that the user has a Contact but also an Admin with a Contact. I could solve this by having two different Contact tables for user and admin, but because it shares the same data it only makes sense to have only one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think your contact entity needs `User` and `Admin` entities also..

Then the fluent api should work:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasRequired(u => u.Contact)
                .WithRequiredPrincipal(c => c.User)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Admin>()
                .HasRequired(a => a.Contact)
                .WithRequiredPrincipal(c => c.Admin)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete();
}
```